# HTTP/s flow with proxy connection

Tags: python, html, http, https, proxy

This days I'm writing a forward proxy.

Ive encountered three problems with the HTTP/s code.
The first one is that whenever I'm trying to handle the redirects [302](from www.google.com for example) I'm not getting any data.
I'm handling the redirects with this code :

```
try:
    response = requests.get("http://"+webserver, timeout=2)
    if response.history:
        print "Redirected to " + response.url
        c = httplib.HTTPSConnection(response.url, port,config['CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'])
    else:
        print "Getting information from " + webserver
        c = httplib.HTTPSConnection(webserver, port,config['CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'])
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print "Getting information from " + webserver
    c = httplib.HTTPSConnection(webserver)
```

If I'm trying to bypass the first error by connecting directly to the redirect url, the second problem appears. The data I'm receiving from the website (any http/s protected website, on the example its www.google.co.il) contains unwanted chars like those question marks : ����� instead of words in Hebrew or Arabic (English works just fine).

I'm handling data with this code:

```
               c = httplib.HTTPSConnection(webserver)
               while 1:
                    c.request("GET", "/")
                    response = c.getresponse()
                    # send request to web server
                    # Indiscriminately forward bytes
                    data = response.read()  # NEED TO DECODE
                    print "DATA : ", data
                    if len(data) > 0:
                        conn.send(data)
                        print "DATA SENT!"
                    else:
                        break
                c.close()
                conn.close()
```

And this is the data I'm receiving (I cannot include everything here, so that's a photo with the html preview of the data): [The data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9UWn.png)

And the last problem I've encountered is that the data is not sent to the browser. The proxy receives the data (as you can see in the second problem) but for some reason it's not forwarding the data to the browser. (the code is the same as the second problem).

The browser show this Error :ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Any help would be very appreciated!

Thanks in advance, Yahli

*Edit: Still couldn't find an answer.I need your help :)

Comment: if don't want google to redirect to your country domain use https://www.google.com/ncr it ll rdirect you to https://www.google.com

Comment: Unfortunately that's not helping me much. I need further help with the other problems first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are reading from the socket there are raw bytes. I think you need to put them into UTF-8 first through [`str.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) as follows:

```
data = response.read().decode('utf8')
```

Please note that the content is not always coded in UTF-8. One would have to check the `Content-Type` HTTP header for each response individually.

Regarding your browser-issue: I suspect you have forgotten to send the appropriate HTTP headers down to the client. Or, in fact, any kind of header section.

Comment: Aight, I've read more about this topic, and I've fixed some of the problems, thanks! Just an FYI tho, the module Requests handle the encoding by defualt accroding to the Content-Type header, so there is no need to encode it again :)